# Ubuntu 18.04 No Wi-Fi Adapter Found - Realtek driver rtl8821ae

Tags: realtek-wireless

I installed a fresh copy on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver on a desktop computer. I have a Realtek usb wifi adapter plugged in.

I am getting the following message:
***Sep 13 17:14:13 data-central systemd[1]: sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlp4s0.device: Job sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlp4s0.device/start timed out.
Sep 13 17:14:13 data-central systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlp4s0.device.
-- Subject: Unit sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlp4s0.device has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support***

I have been unable to find any documentation that describes my error. Can you help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you can install the latest Realtek drivers from this repository
https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git
cd rtw88
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8821ae
```

Comment: sudo make install fails with:
/bin/sh: 1: scripts/basic/fixdep: Exec format error
scripts/Makefile.build:297: recipe for target '/home/nvidia/rtlwifi_new/base.o' failed