# How to reinstall wifi adapter/driver with no internet connection?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, internet

I just removed ubuntu-desktop from my Ubuntu Desktop install with tasksel to clear up some storage space since I don't use the desktop anymore, but during the process my wifi stopped working and the device no longer shows in `ifconfig` or `iwconfig`.

My device is a Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)

When running `lshw -C network`, it shows up as UNCLAIMED.

When running a live Ubuntu Desktop disk it identified the network device and allows me to connect with no issues and I was able to chroot into my main install and update things from there.

This device no longer has internet access, but I can transfer debs/files from another pc if necessary.

How would I restore the device and allow it to connect to wifi again?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Also: `sudo modprobe rtl8188ee && dmesg | grep rtl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: The second command says `ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8188ee': Operation not permitted

Comment: If you reboot, is the response the same? Please show: `uname -r`

Comment: Yeah, rebooting has done nothing. `5.3.0-40-generic`

Comment: Let's see: `ls -al /lib/modules/5.3.0-40-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8188ee/rtl8188ee.ko` As well as: `sudo modprobe /lib/modules/5.3.0-40-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8188ee/rtl8188ee.ko` Also: `dmesg | grep rtl` Very interesting problem!

Comment: The folder structure was a little different, it ended up being `/lib/modules/5.3.0-40-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8188ee/rtl8188ee.ko`, `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 135056 Mar 18 10:40`

The modprobe command failed, `module not found in directory /lib/modules/5.3.0-40-generic`

The dmesg command found nothing

Comment: Did you install rtl8188ee from github or some such? `sudo updatedb && locate rtlwifi | grep 8188ee` And: `locate rtl8188ee.ko`

Comment: Yeah I tried to download it from github and put it in my home folder, but it wouldn't do anything when I tried to make install it

Comment: I suggest that you navigate to the folder, something like: `cd ~/rtlwifi_new` or similar and then do: `sudo make uninstall` and reboot. Any improvement?

Comment: No improvements and all of the same files are there.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything preventing you from using an ethernet cable?

Also, you could possibly use Live USB and mount the ubuntu install.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery

Comment: This machine moves around a lot so I would like the wifi to work, as I said in the post I have done a live usb install and have chrooted into the root partition with internet access, but I do not know how to permanently restore it for when I boot back into the main disk

Comment: I. meant using the ethernet cabel to download the correct drivers
Well through chroot you can run a normal apt install for the relevant drivers and as long as you dismount correctly the new drivers should remain on the install.

Comment: Ok, that sounds great, I don't know how to find the drivers though, since I never installed them in the first place, they came with Ubuntu. Is there a way to find out which ones to download?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416180/ubuntu-no-wifi-adapter-found

See if the commands in that thread don't work.

Comment: That didn't work, it didn't do anything, probably because I have a realtek adapter and not a broadcomm one

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075086/ubuntu-18-04-no-wi-fi-adapter-found-realtek-driver-rtl8821ae - how about this?

Comment: Works until modprobe, I get Operation not permitted even with root