# Realtek Wifi Driver Problem

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek

I have been trying all the possible solutions here and other sites for the last day in order to solve my Wifi connection problem. I do have Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. Whenever I click to check wifi networks I don't see any. It only says no networks.

```
sudo lshw -class network
```

This is the output:

```
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 40:23:43:61:ee:17
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_pci driverversion=5.4.0-42-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:81 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7800000-f780ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 16
       serial: 04:0e:3c:a5:dd:aa
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:54 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7704000-f7704fff memory:f7700000-f7703fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: bnep0
       serial: 40:23:43:61:ee:18
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes ip=192.168.44.13 multicast=yes
```

I tried to install Realtek drivers using this [example](https://askubuntu.com/a/1075115/891365). However, none of my work has given me a positive outcome. Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Edit 1(asked by the user @[chili55](https://askubuntu.com/users/19421/chili555)):

```
rfkill list all
```

Gives the output:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Edit 2: Tried the solution given in [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1291415/891365). It didn't work out as well.

Comment: DISABLED usually means that the hardware switch or key combination is set to disable the wireless radio. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 First of all, thank you for your response. I have updated my output.